# Compare 2 string with Regex (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, string, compare

I have a correct string and then a string come anywhere.
I must compare but this strings maybe not equal.
Example 
Correct string is

```
SAAT:23:34
```

Coming string

```
SAAT:12:23
```

When I compare this strings, Answer must be true.

Patern like this

```
SAAT:..:..
Regex.IsMatch();
```

give me t string but ı dont want to this.

How can I compare two string..

Comment: Insufficient data...  Why is `SAAT:23:34` equal to `SAAT:12:23` ? Would it be equal to `SAAT:xx:yy` ? Or `TAAS.12.23` ?

Comment: I want to discard some character. Exaple Date and Time values not important for me. Is  Other chars equal? I want to know this.

Comment: Still not enough. Add another example and we've got an IQ test.

Comment: Please give to me an IQ test.

Comment: I think he was being clever and wanted you to write something like Sit is to Stand as Walk is to ___ (Run) or something like that. Keep hitting refresh I'm sure an Ad for an IQ test will pop eventually on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided and my lack of caffeine here is a solution:

```
    static bool IsEqual(String left, String right)
    {
        left = Regex.Replace(left, ":[0-9]*:[0-9]*", "");
        right = Regex.Replace(right, ":[0-9]*:[0-9]*", "");
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsEqual("SAAT:232:34", "SAAT:12:23")); // True
        Console.WriteLine(IsEqual("PAAT:23:34", "SAAT:12:23")); // False
        Console.WriteLine(IsEqual("SAAT:23:34:HAT", "SAAT:12:23:HAT")); // True
    }
```

Comment: @Murat No problem. I don't really like the double String replace and was working on other solutions, but if this suites your needs I think I'll move on for now. Good luck.

Comment: This solution is enough for me for now.
Thanks again.
But you have a smart solution, ı want to see it :)